# QML JavaScript GET request

Tags: javascript, rest, xmlhttprequest, qml

I'm trying to make a login form in QML and JavaScript and so far I have created a user in the Advanced Rest Client and tested if the user exists. Now I'm trying to send the data from this login form to authenticate the user but at the moment I am getting an error: *"TypeError: Property 'addEventListener' of object [object Object] is not a function"*

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 640
    title: qsTr("Auth app for UniqCast by Krešimir Čoko")
    style: {
        color: "#F00"
    }

    FontLoader {
        source: "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700"
    }

    // Title
    Text {
        y: 58
        text: "uniqCast"
        font.italic: false
        font.bold: true
        font.family: "montserrat"
        anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: 1
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        color: "#2ecc71"
        font.pixelSize: 41
    }

    // Username
    Text {
        id: usernameLabel
        x: 271
        y: 161
        text: qsTr("Username")
        color: "#34495e"
        font.family: "montserrat"
        font.pixelSize: 21
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: usernameRec
        x: 194
        y: 192
        width: 255
        height: 40
        color: "#EDEDED"
        z: 0

        MouseArea {
            id: usernameMouseArea
            anchors.fill: parent
            z: 1
        }

        TextInput {
            id: usernameInput
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.topMargin: 7
            anchors.rightMargin: 10
            anchors.bottomMargin: 7
            anchors.leftMargin: 10
            z: 2
            font.family: "montserrat"
            color: "#34495e"
            font.pixelSize: 21
            maximumLength: 19
            selectByMouse: true
        }
    }

    // Email
    Text {
        id: emailLabel
        x: 293
        y: 277
        text: qsTr("Email")
        font.family: "montserrat"
        color: "#34495e"
        font.pixelSize: 21
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: emailRec
        x: 194
        y: 309
        width: 255
        height: 40
        color: "#EDEDED"


        MouseArea {
            id: emailMouseArea
            anchors.fill: parent
            z: 1
        }

        TextInput {
            id: emailInput
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.topMargin: 7
            anchors.rightMargin: 10
            anchors.bottomMargin: 7
            anchors.leftMargin: 10
            text: ""
            z: 2
            font.family: "montserrat"
            color: "#34495e"
            font.pixelSize: 21
            maximumLength: 19
            selectByMouse: true
        }
    }

    // Password
    Text {
        id: passLabel
        x: 273
        y: 406
        text: qsTr("Password")
        font.family: "montserrat"
        color: "#34495e"
        font.pixelSize: 21
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: passRec
        x: 194
        y: 437
        width: 255
        height: 40
        color: "#EDEDED"

        MouseArea {
            id: passMouseArea
            anchors.fill: parent
            z: 1
        }

        TextInput {
            id: passInput
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.topMargin: 7
            anchors.rightMargin: 10
            anchors.bottomMargin: 7
            anchors.leftMargin: 10
            text: ""
            z: 2
            font.family: "montserrat"
            maximumLength: 18
            color: "#34495e"
            font.pixelSize: 21
            selectByMouse: true
            echoMode: TextInput.Password
        }
    }


    // Submit Button
    Rectangle {
        id: submitBtnRec
        x: 196
        y: 522
        width: 255
        height: 40
        color: "#2ecc71"

        Text {
            id: submitLabel
            x: 84
            y: 8
            text: qsTr("SUBMIT")
            z: 1
            font.family: "montserrat"
            color: "#FEFEFE"
            font.pixelSize: 21
            font.weight: Font.ExtraBold
        }

        MouseArea {
            id: submitMouseArea
            x: 0
            y: 0
            width: 255
            height: 40
            z: 2
            onClicked: {
                var identifier = TextInput.username;
                var password = TextInput.password;
                var url = "http://176.31.182.158:3001/auth/local";
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true);
                xmlhttp.send();

                xmlhttp.addEventListener("readystatechange", processRequest, false);
                function processRequest(e) {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
                        // If done execute code
                        var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                        MessageDialog:  {
                            text: "Success"
                        }
                    } else {
                        MessageDialog: {
                            text: "Failure"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: as far as I remember, javascript in QML is somewhat different. Its better to follow Qt docs for examples: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-xmlhttprequest-get-qml.html

Comment: @VladimirM I'm not that good at either QML or JavaScript to be able to redo the code in that documentation but for my specific example. From what I can see, that documentation has nothing about the user input.

Comment: QML implementation of XMLHttpRequest is different from the HTML one. [The QT docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-qmlglobalobject.html#xmlhttprequest). So just refer to the example above.

Comment: @folibis, can you help me implement it into this code? I've been tackling QML for about 3 days now, so I have no idea how to adapt it.

Comment: I guess you should start learning `QML` from some simple examples or tutorials. The example above is very simple and I don't see how can I help you over that.